# Raise an error manually in T-SQL to jump to BEGIN CATCH block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exception, try-catch

Is it possible to raise an error in a stored procedure manually to stop execution and jump to `BEGIN CATCH` block? Some analog of `throw new Exception()` in `C#`.

Here is my stored procedure's body:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

-- do something

IF @foobar IS NULL
    -- here i want to raise an error to rollback transaction    

-- do something next

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@trancount > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH
```

I know one way: `SELECT 1/0` But it's awful!!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

you can use `raiserror`. Read more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

--from MSDN

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution to 
    -- jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
    -- information about the original error that caused
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH;
```

**EDIT**
  If you are using SQL Server 2012+ you can use `throw` clause. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql) are the details.

Answer (score 18):

You could use `THROW` (available in SQL Server 2012+):

```
THROW 50000, 'Your custom error message', 1
THROW <error_number>, <message>, <state>
```

[MSDN THROW (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)

[Differences Between RAISERROR and THROW in Sql Server](http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Can't use 'THROW' within a function. Sad.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).

From MSDN:

> Generates an error message and
>   initiates error processing for the
>   session. RAISERROR can either
>   reference a user-defined message
>   stored in the sys.messages catalog
>   view or build a message dynamically.
>   The message is returned as a server
>   error message to the calling
>   application or to an associated CATCH
>   block of a TRY…CATCH construct.

CodeProject has a [good article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Raiserror.aspx) that also describes in-depth the details of how it works and how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

SQL has an error raising mechanism

```
RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable }
{ ,severity ,state }
[ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] )
[ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]
```

Just look up Raiserror in the Books Online. But.. you have to generate an error of the appropriate severity, an error at severity 0 thru 10 do not cause you to jump to the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

### [THROW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql)

Raises an exception and transfers execution to a CATCH block of a TRY…CATCH construct in SQL Server 2017.

Please refer the below link

[T-SQL Throw Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377065/t-sql-throw-exception)