# Incorrect syntax near Throw - what am I missing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute a THROW statement like so (`value` and `12345` being some random values):

```
use testdb;
go

begin try
if('value' in (select distinct shelf from itemloc))
update itemloc
set shelf = 'value'
where item = '12345';
end try
begin catch
;Throw 160073, 'Failed to update shelf value', 1;
end catch;
```

Using [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql)

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003153/incorrect-syntax-near-throw) and I have the `;` before my `THROW`. I'm also checking the syntax against the reference and fail to see why executing this returns

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Throw'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inside a `CATCH`, you can't choose your error here, you would just use `THROW;`. Also, you don't need to start your statement with a semicolon, you already put one at the end of your last statement. It's a terminator (it goes at the end of the line), not at the beginning and end.

If you want to use a custom error, use `RAISERROR`. For example:

```
USE TESTDB;
GO

BEGIN TRY    
    IF('value' IN (SELECT DISTINCT shelf FROM itemloc))
        UPDATE itemloc
        SET shelf = 'value'
        WHERE item = '12345';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ERROR VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @ERROR = 'Failed to update shelf value';
    RAISERROR(@ERROR, 11, 160073); 
END CATCH
```

Comment: Even if I just do `begin catch throw; end catch;` it still gives me the same error. But your answer works, so thank you for a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Add colons,

```
IF 'A'='A'
BEGIN;
  THROW 51000, 'ERROR', 1;
END;
```

Comment: _"Add colons"_, but your answer doesn't contain any...