# Error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertCustomers, Line 30 Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'

Tags: t-sql

I have a table called Sales.Customers with the following columns:`custid, companyname, contactname, contacttitle, address, city, postalcode, country, phone, fax`.
I need to create a stored procedure called 'Sales.InsertCustomers' that inserts data into the Customers table.
The stored procedure must meet the following requirements:

- Data changes occur as a single unit of work.
- Data modifications that are successful are committed and a value of
  O is returned.
- Data modifications that are unsuccessful are rolled back. The
  exception severity level is set to 16 and a value of -1 is returned.
- The stored procedure uses a built-it scalar function to evaluate
  the current condition of data modifications.
- The entire unit of work is terminated and rolled back if a run-time
  error occurs during execution of the stored procedure.

Here is the code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.InsertCustomers
   @Companyname nvarchar(100),
   @ContactName nvarchar(100),
   @Contacttitle nvarchar(100),
   @Address nvarchar(100),
   @City nvarchar(80),
   @PostalCode nvarchar(20),
   @country nvarchar(50),
   @phone nvarchar(20),
   @fax nvarchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
       SET XACT_ABORT ON 

BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION 
       INSERT INTO Sales.Customers(companyname, contactname, contacttitle, address, city, postalcode, country, phone, fax)

       VALUES(@Companyname, @ContactName, @Contacttitle, @Address, @City, @PostalCode, @country, @phone, @fax)

      COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
      IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      PRINT 'Unable to create a customer record.'
      THROW
      RETURN -1
 END CATCH
RETURN 0
END;
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertCustomers, Line 30 Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003153/incorrect-syntax-near-throw)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) link.

> The statement before the THROW statement must be followed by the
>   semicolon (;) statement terminator.

So your `PRINT` statement should be ending with semicolon.

```
PRINT 'Unable to create a customer record.';
```

OR you can do.

```
;THROW
```

Comment: Oh my, You're  such a great helper. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries. Please upvote/mark as answer if it solved your problem to close the question.

Comment: I marked it. It didn't know that I am supposed to mark it. Now I know that if, the response solves the problem, to close the question you are supposed to upvote/mark.

Comment: @resursibanda it's not mandatory but simply helps other people who may find this question with similar issue.

Comment: Ok. I've heard you, but the challenge is I'm still studying and I can't help on stuff that I've not yet covered. I see some of the questions, willing to answer, but because I have shallow knowledge I just leave the question unattended.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates, flag that they are duplicates & when you have rep vote to close.